# Django ORM group by one column and return other

Tags: python, django, orm

In simple worlds I try to write in Django a query which will return results

Similar to this:

```
select id, max(score), screen, details from results
group by screen
where user_id=123
order by score desc, screen
```

My code:

```
results = Results.objects.filter(user=user).values('screen').annotate(score=Max('score')).order_by('-score', 'screen')
```

But i doesn't return Results objects but json. I would like to get results as Results object like

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=id)
results = Results.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-score', 'screen')
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

It is the [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) call that  turns your `QuerySet`
into a list of `dicts`.

If you want to keep it a `QuerySet`, but only retrieve the fields from the database that you are interested in, use [`only(*fields)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) or [`defer(*fields)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer)

```
results = Results.objects.filter(user=user)
                         .annotate(score=Max('score'))
                         .order_by('-score', 'screen')
                         .only('screen')  # not values()
```

If you try to access fields that were deferred on instances it will result in extra db hits. You can verify that these are incomplete `Results` instances:

```
> type(results[0])
<class 'app_name.Results_Deferred_foo_bar_7265632c0017c141e84a00d9fdb4760'>
```